# MethodNotAllowedHttpException statusCode 405

Tags: laravel

```
Route::get('/flutterwave','FlutterwaveController@flutterwave_process');
Route::get('/verify','FlutterwaveController@flutterwave_verfiy')->name('flutterwave.verify');
```

controller:

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FlutterwaveController extends Controller
{

     public function flutterwave_process(Request $request){

     // $user = Auth::user();
     // $subs = Subscription::findOrFail($request->subs_id);
     // $settings = Generalsetting::findOrFail(1);
     $PBFPubKey = '*************************************';
     $name = 'Danish';
     $customer_email = '***********';
     $currency = "ZMW";

     $amount = '100';
     $redirect_url = route('flutterwave.verify');

     $txref = "rave-".substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 100); // ensure you generate unique references per transaction.

     $curl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.ravepay.co/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/v2/hosted/pay",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
            'amount'=>$amount,
            'customer_email'=>$customer_email,
            'currency'=>$currency,
            'txref'=>$txref,
            'PBFPubKey'=>$PBFPubKey,
            'redirect_url'=>$redirect_url
        ]),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "content-type: application/json",
            "cache-control: no-cache"
        ],
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        $err = curl_error($curl);

        if($err){
        // there was an error contacting the rave API
        die('Curl returned error: ' . $err);
        }

        $transaction = json_decode($response);

        if(!$transaction->data && !$transaction->data->link){
        // there was an error from the API
        print_r('API returned error: ' . $transaction->message);
        }

        // uncomment out this line if you want to redirect the user to the payment page
        //print_r($transaction->data->message);


        // redirect to page so User can pay
        // uncomment this line to allow the user redirect to the payment page
        // header('Location: ' . $transaction->data->link);
        return redirect($transaction->data->link);
}
public function flutterwave_verfiy(Request $request){
            dd($request);
    }
}
```

When i run the url `http://localhost/flutterwave/public/flutterwave` then this function call `flutterwave_process` in the controller
after this payment gateway process and return a get response with
`http://localhost/flutterwave/public/verify?flwref=FLW-MOCK-0870181f99da0fb09e539031ec86fb22&txref=rave-lqq5yt2fs7k8s0kks4gosc8kkwo8084`
But it return the error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` status code 405.

I tried to solve this problem but not solved yet
Please anyone give me guide to solve this

Comment: You set as `GET` here and trying as `POST`

Comment: If i remove the Request $request from the parameter then i show me the same error

Comment: @RishiRaut sir i need your help.I'm stuck on this error from the last two day but not solved

Comment: can you show  me the routes ?

Comment: @LalitKumar
Route::get('/flutterwave','FlutterwaveController@flutterwave_process');
Route::get('/verify','FlutterwaveController@flutterwave_verfiy')->name('flutterwave.verify');

Sir these are my route

Comment: I think you  are get response in POST from server . try like that

Route::get('/verify','FlutterwaveController@flutterwave_verfiy');

Route::post('/verify','FlutterwaveController@responsedata');

print $request in this responsedata function

Comment: @LalitKumar
https://webhookdanish.000webhostapp.com/fl.PNG
sir when i tried and change th url it's show me this error.I attach a link
Please take a look

Comment: this error come when token expire

Comment: So what i do for this?

Comment: try to comment the the VerifyCsrfToken or check your session

try to clear cache  
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache

Comment: Please anyone can solve this problem?

Comment: @LalitKumar i clear the cache and run all the command that you say ,also run auto dump commad but it's same return the error "The page has expired due to inactivity.

Please refresh and try again"

Comment: If you want to see the code then i upload it on my domain.
It's simple only two routes that i already send you and only one controller

Comment: okay show me the code

Comment: username: webhookdanish
passwrod : danish123

https://files.000webhost.com/

in the public_html a directory with the name of flutterwave
there all the code

Comment: @InoxentLarka I have seen your file directory. I have updated your `web.php` and `/public_html/flutterwave/flutterwave/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`.

Comment: @InoxentLarka If I want to test your project what is your URL?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya http://webhookdanish.000webhostapp.com/flutterwave/flutterwave/
but it's not work on the server .I think maybe here we have to update the composer but i try it on my localhost ,there it's working fine.Could i get you skype or something othere?
Thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

If post request coming and you want except `VerifyCsrfToken` then update.

`app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

    class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
    {

         protected $except = [
             'verify',
         ];
    }
```

Comment: @InoxentLarka No I gave not on sky. But tell me what is problem on the server?

Comment: I also don't know ,I upload the laravel script on the server first time
As usually when i donwlaod the the project from git then it's show the same error that is shown on my server 
ON my localhost i update the composer and run key:generate after this it's work fine
but here i don't know how to run the php artisan command